# How to perform a search and replace when editing a Google Sites page?

Tags: google-classic-sites

There doesn't seem to be such a built-in feature.

Copying the entire page into some other app (web or desktop) for replacing text causes partial loss/distortion of formatting when pasting the content back.

Answer (score 1):

Go into HTML mode, copy the HTML to a text-editor (notepad or suchlike) and do the change there.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by running the following appscript via https://script.google.com/ :

```
function searchAndReplace() {

  page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl('https://sites.google.com/....');
  var html = page.getHtmlContent();
  html = html.replace(/old/, "new");
  page.setHtmlContent(html);

};
```

Obviously, you should replace `old` and `new` with your own strings.